# Magento checkout.setMethod() : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototype

I'm moving a Magento 1.3 template to Magento 1.9. I'll have to fix a lot of little bugs but this one is too complicated for me.

When I'm on the onpage checkout and choose to buy as a guest and try to click the link:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="checkout.setMethod();" id="onepage-guest-register-button" type="button" class="button">weiter zum nächsten Schritt</a>
```

Then the following error appears:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
>
> Element.Methods.hide @ prototype.js:1590
>
> Checkout.setMethod @ opcheckout.js:103onclick @ (index):277

I know that `protoype.js` doesn't find an element with a specific id on that side, but I don't know what id, or am I just wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive fixed the Problem. The Problem was that the Element that get display none had the wrong id.